# Odd numberOfItems in UICollectionVIew

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview

I am using `UICollectionView` and my app crashes because I have odd number of items in my `list` but while I need to tow the items in section.

This is my the numbet of items in every section:

```
(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 2;
}
```

Here is the problem:
In my list i have 3 items and when the objectAtIndex is 3 the app crashes

```
 MSCoupon *coupon = [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.section * 2 + indexPath.row];
```

Do you have any solution for me?

Comment: What crash log do you get? Also, what are the values of indexPath (row and section) when it crashes etc...

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'

tell me please is there a way that even if i mentioned that in one section will be 2 items can i put there only one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is as follows:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
  //return 2;
   return [list count];
}
```

and:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
   //return [list count]/2;
   return 1;
}
```

Do you have a better advice for me?

Comment: this is the best. i don't think i have more better advice

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because collection view is trying to access the 2nd element of 2nd section. which resulting in crash because your formula creating index 3.

For second element of section section Your formula

```
indexPath.section * 2 + indexPath.row
```

gives

```
1*2 + 1 = 3
```

Since your array have 3 element only it will through exception when you try to access fourth element.(array index start with 0).
In Collection view delegate you write this formula. leave rest of your code un-touch it should work

```
(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section { 
  return (list.count/(section + 1)) >= 2? 2: 1; 
}
```

Comment: Hello Sunil,

Do you have a solution for me?
Now it works Because i tried this solution:

    - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view     numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        //return 2;
        return [list count];
    }

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView     *)collectionView
    {
        //return [list count]/2;
        return 1;
    }

but this is not a good solution...

Comment: There is still a problem:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: please check collectionview delegate i hade made little mistake

Comment: look like everything is correct... did you see my answer below?

Comment: Yes i thought you need two section but you were now compromising with only one section.